# JSR-303 Default message is never displayed

Tags: spring-mvc, bean-validation

I have JSR-303 bean validation working, but I can never get the default message to be displayed.

I have created a custom validator, `DateRangeValidator`, that checks two dates to ensure the **from** date is before the **to** date. It works correctly.

My annotation looks like this:

```
@Target( ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention( RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = DateRangeValidator.class)
public @interface ValidDateRange {
    String message() default "{ValidDateRange.message}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

In `messages.properties` I have the following:

`ValidDateRange.message=From date must be before to date.`

But whenever validation fails, all I see on the webpage is:

> {ValidDateRange.message}

What am I missing here? Where is my default message?

The only way I can get a message to be displayed is to add the following into `messages.properties` (without the curly braces):

```
ValidDateRange.{myFormName}.{myRangeField}=blah blah blah
```

**Why is the default message never displayed?** I don't wan to to have to specify a message for every field where I use this validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The ValidationMessages resource bundle is typically a properties file,
>   ValidationMessages.properties, in the default package of an
>   application.

Comment: when you drop something into src/main/resources it will end up at the root of your archive. This is the default package.